# Auto Layout: understanding the behavior of attributes and items

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I use Auto Layout programmatically a lot but there are still two things that I do not understand.

1. What is the difference between `leading` and `left` attribute/anchor and between `trailing` and `right` attribute/anchor?

To me there seem to be the same but according to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutAnchor_ClassReference/):

> However, Auto Layout does not allow constraints that mix leading and trailing attributes with left or right attributes. As a result, this constraint crashes at runtime.

2. The order of the the items inside the `NSLayoutConstraint` does not matter for the Auto Layout system at all, am I right? (At least for `.Equal` relation.)

Do not get confused about the attributes for each individual item, I'm aware of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Left and right are always left and right.

Leading and trailing are not. From [Working with Constraints in Interface Builder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html):

> If you lay out your views using leading and trailing constraints, the views automatically flip positions when switching between left-to-right languages (like English) and right-to-left languages (like Arabic). However, some interface elements should not change their position based on the reading direction. For example, buttons that are based on physical directions (up, down, left, and right) should always stay in the same relative orientation.

The order of items for an equal relation is irrelevant.

Comment: You can also use [`semanticContentAttribute`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/semanticContentAttribute) to customize the behavior of certain groups of views while still using leading/trailing

Comment: So it's better to use `leading` and `trailing` attributes/anchors instead of `left` and `right` ones, because `semanticContentAttribute` will flip the view if needed?! Imagine VFL like this `H:|-[someView]-[label]-|` and if our `label` will use `leadingAnchor` and `trailingAnchor` for that VFL, so what will happen for right-to-left languages? `someView.trailing = label.leading` will never change but the label will still flip?

Comment: It would be nice if you additionally could provide a little example (not actual code).

Comment: @DevAndArtist Last year's WWDC session, *New UIKit Support for International User Interfaces*, has a pretty good demo.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between `leading` and `left` is important when taking into account RTL languages, such as Hebrew. In that case, the UI is inverted to complement text direction, and so are the UI elements with constraints. In this case, `leading` means the side where text starts. `left` is always left, for text direction agnostic UIs, such as media playback controls.

The order constraints are placed in does not matter. If there are conflicting constraints, the behavior is undefined.